# Rails fields change value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have 3 models `Currency`, `NeuralNetwork`, `Prediction`. Each currency has a neural network associated to it that creates a prediction.

Every time the currency's `update` method is called, it asks the neural network to generate a new prediction or it uses the prediction already generated. The currency `has_one` neural network, which `has_one` prediction.

The currency controller:

```
def update
    if @currency.update(currency_params)
      prediction = @currency.neural_network.predict
      redirect_to prediction
    end
  end
```

The neural network's model

```
  def predict
    if(self.prediction == nil)
      #some other code
      (0..29).each do |i|
        #ASS: I'm getting the data for today at the beginning of the day
        self.prediction.exchange_rates << ExchangeRate.new(last: predicted_rates[i], date: Date.today + i + 1, predicted: true)
      end
    end
    p "there are #{self.prediction.exchange_rates.size} predicted rates"
    self.prediction
  end
```

My problem is that if the controller method is called twice, the following is printed:

```
    there are 30 predicted rates
    there are 0 predicted rates
```

Why does the field change its value? Why aren't the objects created in the loop remembered?

Comment: I think it's because you are not saving `prediction`, so it is again going into loop second time also as `self.prediction == nil` is condition is again `true`

Comment: Even if call `prediction.save`, I still get the same output.

Comment: see if second time also it is going into the loop, puts something in loop

Comment: It is not and it shouldn't because the prediction was already constructed.